# Include custom post type content in search

Tags: custom-post-types, search, theme-twenty-sixteen

I created a custom post type (called 'produits') with the CPT UI plugin. I checked that both its parameters and Yoast SEO's allow custom post types to display in search results.

I tried to use several methods to include the custom post types in the global search results, such as [this one](http://www.remicorson.com/include-all-your-wordpress-custom-post-types-in-search/) and [this one](https://thomasgriffin.io/how-to-include-custom-post-types-in-wordpress-search-results/), I tried to use plugins too (such as Relevanssi and Search Everything) : nothing worked. In the following code though, I can echo the array content (the post types) correctly, so I suppose the problem is elsewhere :

```
function rc_add_cpts_to_search($query) {
    if( is_search() ) { 
        $post_types = get_post_types(array('public' => true, 'exclude_from_search' => false), 'objects');
        $searchable_types = array();
        if( $post_types ) {
            foreach( $post_types as $type) {
                $searchable_types[] = $type->name;
            }
        }
        $query->set( 'post_type', $searchable_types );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_add_cpts_to_search' );
```

I'm not a developper, maybe I am overlooking something basic ? I don't really know where to search next, so... any help would be very welcome :)

I'm using WP 4.7.5, and a modified twenty-sixteen theme.

Edit for Doug
As I used a plugin to generate the CPT, I'm not sure if the following code is what you need (I found it in the plugin page) :

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_produits() {

/**
 * Post Type: Produits.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( 'Produits', '' ),
    "singular_name" => __( 'Produit', '' ),
    "menu_name" => __( 'Produits', '' ),
    "all_items" => __( 'Tous les produits', '' ),
    "add_new" => __( 'Créer un nouveau produit', '' ),
    "add_new_item" => __( 'Créer un nouveau produit', '' ),
    "edit_item" => __( 'Modifier un produits', '' ),
    "search_items" => __( 'Rechercher un produit', '' ),
    "not_found" => __( 'Aucun produit n'a été trouvé', '' ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( 'Produits', '' ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "Liste des produits Easy -Connect",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => false,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "produits", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "custom-fields" ),
    "taxonomies" => array( "spot" ),
);

register_post_type( "produits", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_produits' );
```

**UPDATE :**

So, after days of tests, it seems that when I deactivate Polylang, custom post types do come up in the search results. 
I [found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472370/wp-query-wont-return-one-of-the-custom-post-types-when-multiple-post-types-requ), who seemed to have the same problem and solved it. But I can't apply the same correction : the plugin UI may have evolved since this post.

Comment: Could you post your CPT registration code, please?

Comment: Hi Doug, I just edited the post. Hope this helps !

Comment: @Petipain you should use `$query->is_search()` rather than `is_search()`, else it will apply those changes to every query on the search page, not just the search queries, also there's a syntax issue with a single quote/apostrophe in the middle of a string in your registration code

Comment: @TomJNowell I just corrected that, and fixed the syntax quote. Doesn't solve the search issue, but it sure is cleaner, thanks :)

Comment: @Petipain it won't but if you're on a search page, that filter would change every query, such as related posts, widgets, footer stuff etc

Comment: @Tom can you drop a link to a page describing `$query->is_search()` vs `is_search()`? I'd like to see if similar logic applies to `is_tax()` and others.

Comment: @Slam `is_search` is just a wrapper function that wraps around the global query objects `is_search` method. The difference is that `is_search` *always* refers to the main query. In `pre_get_posts` you're evaluating a specific query, that isn't always the main query

Comment: I still had issues with `$query->is_search()` affecting my custom navigation and pagination. I solved it by using `$query->is_main_query()`, but I don't understand yet how that works.